# Override Djange ImageField extension validation

Tags: django, django-models

Understand I can add a validator to Django's ImageField validators to restrict file extension types like below. But in terms of the error messages which are displayed via upload on Admin -- I'm still seeing the standard file type list (via PIL allowed types), if I upload a non-image type. If I upload an image type which is not in my custom allowed_extensions below, I see my custom message. How can I override Django's default ImageField handling, and show my custom error message no matter what type of file is uploaded (e.g. when any file other than .png is uploaded per below example)?

```
class MM(models.Model):
    file_extension_validator = FileExtensionValidator(
        allowed_extensions=['png'],
        message='File extension not allowed. Allowed extensions include  .png'
    )

    image = models.ImageField(
        help_text='Upload images only (.png).',
        validators=[file_extension_validator],
        max_length=255,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
```

Comment: The custom message content isn't the problem... It's something to do with subclassing I assume. It checks against Django's ImageFile class implementation first, and if it is a non-image file, it shows Django's standed error response which includes a huge list of allowed PIL image file types.

Comment: For reference, this is the allowed extensions based on PIL which are included in the standard message response, when trying to upload a non image file type: "Allowed extensions are: bmp, dib, gif, tif, tiff, jfif, jpe, jpg, jpeg, pbm, pgm, ppm, pnm, png, apng, blp, bufr, cur, pcx, dcx, dds, ps, eps, fit, fits, fli, flc, ftc, ftu, gbr, grib, h5, hdf, jp2, j2k, jpc, jpf, jpx, j2c, icns, ico, im, iim, mpg, mpeg, mpo, msp, palm, pcd, pdf, pxr, psd, bw, rgb, rgba, sgi, ras, tga, icb, vda, vst, webp, wmf, emf, xbm, xpm."

Comment: If it were a forms ImageField, I could add something like this, but doesn't work at the model field level. error_messages={'invalid_extension': 'custom message'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the model field, but the form field. The form field has a default validator that lists all the extensions PIL supports.

You can make a special form field `ModifiedImageField` and specify that for the `ModelForm` that will be used by the `MyModelAdmin` in this case:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from django import forms

image_validator = FileExtensionValidator(
    allowed_extensions=['png'],
    message='File extension not allowed. Allowed extensions include  .png'
)

class ModifiedImageField(forms.ImageField):
    default_validators = [image_validator]

class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    imagefield = ModifiedImageField()

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
```

where *`imagefield`* is the name of the `ImageField` for which you want to replace the validator.